# How do I have a private PyPI repo cache downloaded packages?

Tags: python, server, pip, private, pypi

I recently spun up a private PyPI repo at work for the purposes of having internal packages. I noticed, however, that the vanilla, out-of-the-box server doesn't have any local packages. I figured that wasn't all bad, since I noticed that even if I hit that server it would re-direct to the public PyPI to download packages so long as the option to mirror was set. The annoying part, however, is that even though it redirects my pip client to an outside server to download a package that's not stored locally, after it's done redirecting, it doesn't download and cache that package in the private server, which seems dumb since the fact a client downloaded said package means future clients might too.

So what I'm wondering is if there's a way to set this functionality that doesn't require me manually downloading the packages and putting them under the packages directory of my private server? Such that if I, as a client, download a package through the private server that causes it to go out to the public server and get it, it will store it locally so future downloads won't have to go out to the public server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you use [pypiserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver)?

Comment: You can use [DevPi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/). It's a private PyPi server + proxy and cache to the official PyPi. Also, use a recent version of `pip`.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov I am using pypiserver.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I'm going to attempt to find a solution that involves the standard, vanilla pypiserver first, hopefully. I've already set it up, so if I can solve the issue without needing to dissolve my server and start over, that'd be better. If not, I will circle back to your suggestion.

Thanks! :)